# CSS display: inline-block drops to next line

Tags: html, css

I have a simple grid that I am testing out.

I decided to change something from `float: left` to `display: inline-block` in the attribute selector `[class*='col-]`.

I am wondering why when using `float: left` there is enough space for `col-9` and everything works fine but, when using `display: inline-block` the element drops down to the next line.

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.header {
 border: 1px solid red;
 padding: 15px;
}

.col-1 {width: 8.33%;}
.col-2 {width: 16.66%;}
.col-3 {width: 25%;}
.col-4 {width: 33.33%;}
.col-5 {width: 41.66%;}
.col-6 {width: 50%;}
.col-7 {width: 58.33%;}
.col-8 {width: 66.66%;}
.col-9 {width: 75%;}
.col-10 {width: 83.33%;}
.col-11 {width: 91.66%;}
.col-12 {width: 100%;}

[class*='col-'] {
 display: inline-block;
 padding-top: 15px;
 border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
 <div class='header'>
  <h1>China</h1>
 </div>
 <div class='row'>
  <div class='col-3'>
   <ul>
    <li>The Flight</li>
    <li>The City</li>
    <li>The Island</li>
    <li>The Food</li>
   </ul>
  </div>
  <div class='col-9'>
   <h1>The City</h1>
   <p>Chania is the capital of the Chania region on the island of Crete. The city can be divided in two parts, the old town and the modern city.</p>
   <p>Resize the browser window to see how the content respond to the resizing.</p>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: I haven't checked your code, but inline elements are sensitive to the whitespace characters around them, which can take up space. They're probably rendering and pushing your elements around

Comment: Remove the space between `.col-9` and `.col-3`. Refer to https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<div class='header'>
        <h1>China</h1>
    </div>
    <div class='row'>
        <div class='col-3'>
            <ul>
                <li>The Flight</li>
                <li>The City</li>
                <li>The Island</li>
                <li>The Food</li>
            </ul>
        </div><!--
        --><div class='col-9'>
            <h1>The City</h1>
            <p>Chania is the capital of the Chania region on the island of Crete. The city can be divided in two parts, the old town and the modern city.</p>
            <p>Resize the browser window to see how the content respond to the resizing.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

small hack, try these `<!-- -->` it ignores the whitespace

**EDIT:** and if you want to remove the tiny gap to your header:

```
.col-9 {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ujfxs70b/)

Comment: Though this is a clever solution it causes a gap at the top of `col-*` when the browser window is at different widths.

Comment: Ha! Thanks! What a great hack!

Answer (score 2):

@Thielicious's answer has a fine solution. Here's the explanation, and the answer to your

> I am wondering **why** when using `float: left` there is enough space for `col-9` and everything works fine but, when using `display: inline-block` the element drops down to the next line.

*Whitespace between `inline-block` elements takes up space on the rendered page.*

Chris Coyier gives [a run down of different ways to get around this](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/) (includes the method of html comments, as in Thielicious's answer, as well as some other HTML tricks and CSS methods)